# How to download such files with Selenium

Tags: selenium

some browsers have functionally to download video by pressing on 3 dots on the right-bottom corner. These dots aren't in HTML code, they are created initially by browser.
Can I use selenium to press on those 3 dots and download after video ?

There are links to photoes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljEcr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACIAP.png

If answer is "Yes" how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium to do this. Use the web dev tools in your browser to find the source, and use a library like `requests`, or `urllib` to directly download it.

But if you were to do it with selenium, you'd set the css hover property of the video player object to true.

Comment: I have to automaticsize process, that's why I want with Selenium.
I don't find something in html source of site 
https://i.imgur.com/dVFOyGc.png

Comment: Ok. Well, I've added the selenium solution to the answer. But using another library to directly download it will also give more control of the download location, and other things like that. It could still be used in an automated process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is certainly possible and quite easy. Using selenium you can just write some simple python code to press the button like shown in this example: https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Also here is the link to the full selenium documentation for reference: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Comment: But the problem is that button it isn't inside of html code - https://i.imgur.com/dVFOyGc.png

Comment: Do you have a link to the video playing website?

Comment: I can't give to you this link. But it works with all videos that are stocked on server and have access directly from call to them via path.

Comment: Ah, ok. I assume you are using some sort of web server to host the videos. This means that if you cannot get the html id of the 3 dots button then you probably cannot use selenium. Another option is just using pyautogui to click the button (if you tell it which pixel to click).

Comment: Thank you !)))))

Comment: How to find сordinates of button in pixels ? Can I  do it by pressing F12 ?

Comment: You can easily do it using pyautogui (using pyautogui.position()). Then just hover over the three dots button and it will show you its coordinates

Comment: Or use the on hover html property, then you will be able to find it in the html code.

Comment: They said that the html for the button does not show because it is a video hosted by the server (above)